# spring websocket rabbitmq external relay in multiserver environment does not scale

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq

In my app i have a frontend that connects via gateway to two instances of the same microservice, configured with an external rabbitmq broker,
everything is good if i launch only one ms instance, but the following scenario occurs when i deploy 2 instances:

1. user login and make a websocket connection to the ms A
2. user triggers a web rest endpoint , that gets load balanced into ms A, the ms fetch the simp session id from the websocket user registry, and send a message to the subscribed channel, no errors
3. user client sees the websocket data as expected
4. user triggers again the same web rest endpoint, that gets load balanced into ms B, the ms fetch the simp session id from the websocket user registry, and send a message to the subscribed channel, no errors
5. the request never arrives to the broker or to the client/browser, the logs shows the following in StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler:

```
No TCP connection for session oxsyxbwp in GenericMessage [payload=byte[1094], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, nativeHeaders={simpOrigDestination=[/user/exchange/amq.direct/get-notifications]}, contentType=application/json, simpSessionId=oxsyxbwp, simpDestination=/exchange/amq.direct/get-notifications-useroxsyxbwp}]
```

and digging into the source code i see that the broker returns without sending the message if tcp connection is not present

**Expected**:

to be able to succesfully publish message for a user websocket subscription, even from the microservice instance that didn't create the websocket connection/session to the client, since i'm using an external broker, and spring is supposed to alert the other server that "own" the websocket session, as far as i understand? Otherwise why would someone bother with an external broker relay?

this is the relevant configuration

```
   @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue", "/exchange/")
            .setAutoStartup(Boolean.TRUE)
            .setSystemHeartbeatReceiveInterval(50000)
            .setSystemHeartbeatSendInterval(50000)
            .setRelayHost(applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getRelayhost())
            .setRelayPort(applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getRelayport())
            .setClientLogin(applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getLogin())
            .setSystemLogin(applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getLogin())
            .setSystemPasscode(applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getPasscode())
            .setClientPasscode(applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getPasscode())
            .setTcpClient(createTcpClient())

            .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved.user.dest")
            .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/registry.broadcast");

        config.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");

    }
   private ReactorNettyTcpClient<byte[]> createTcpClient() {

        return new ReactorNettyTcpClient<>(applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getRelayhost(),
            applicationProperties.getWebsocket().getRelayport(),
            new StompReactorNettyCodec());
   }
```

this is how i publish messages:

```
public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "/exchange/amq.direct/get-notifications";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_DEST = "/user/exchange/amq.direct/get-notifications";

 retrieveWebsocketSessionId(jhiUserId, users)
                .ifPresent(sessionId ->
                    // send to user
                    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                        sessionId,
                        CHANNEL_NAME,
                        notificationList,
                        simpMessageHelper.createHeaders(sessionId)
                    )
                );

    private Optional<String> retrieveWebsocketSessionId(String jhiUserId, Set<SimpUser> users) {
        for (SimpUser user : users) {
            if (user.getName().equals(jhiUserId)) {
                for (SimpSession session : user.getSessions()) {
                    // find if that session has our subscription associated
                    for (SimpSubscription sub : session.getSubscriptions()) {
                        if (sub.getDestination().equals(NOTIFICATION_DEST)) {
                            log.info("user {} is logged in. forwarding message to destination {} with session Id: {}", jhiUserId, sub.getDestination(), session.getId());
                            return Optional.of(session.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        log.info("user {} currently is not logged in or he hasn't a websocket connection yet. discard message", jhiUserId);
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

thank you in advance for any pointers or clarifications

p.s. version: spring-boot-starter-websocket\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-websocket-2.7.3.pom

**EDIT**:
as a "workaround" i changed my flow as follow: every instance of the microservice gets the notification message from a queue (actually in my full system the rest api invoked send a message in a rabbitmq queue, and the notification microservice read the message, perform some logic and push it to the websocket connection)

then the instance check if the user is actually connected to the websocket local registry, if so push the message to the websocket, otherwise it exits without doing nothing

this is how i collect the info about an user being connected to the local instance:

```
  // map of jhiUserId / simpSessionId, or null if not connected to the instance
    private Map<String, String> connectedSessionsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    @EventListener
    public void handleBrokerAvailabilityEvent(BrokerAvailabilityEvent event) {
        log.info("Broker rabbitmq available: {}", event.isBrokerAvailable());
        connectedSessionsMap.clear();
    }
    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionDisconnectEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headers = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
        Principal principal = headers.getUser();
        if (principal != null) {
            String username = principal.getName();
            log.info("Websocket session disconnected, user: {} sessionId: {}, populating connectedSessionsMap cache", username, headers.getSessionId());
            connectedSessionsMap.put(username, null);
        } else {
            log.warn("WARNING: no principal found for ws disconnected event: {} , message: {}", event, event.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionConnectEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headers = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
        Principal principal = headers.getUser();
        if (principal != null) {
            String username = principal.getName();
            log.info("Websocket session connect, user: {} sessionId: {}, populating connectedSessionsMap cache", username, headers.getSessionId());
            connectedSessionsMap.put(username, headers.getSessionId());
        } else {
            log.warn("WARNING: no principal found for ws connect event: {} , message: {}", event, event.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

this is the logic the read from the message queue and propagate the message to the websocket

```
  @RabbitListener(queues = "#{exportQueue.getName()}")
    public void listen(BaseMessage<ExportMessageDTO> inMessage) {

        log.info("Received message from rabbitmq broker {} , {} {}", inMessage, exportQueue.getName(), exportQueue.getActualName());


        String id = inMessage.getPrincipalId();
        String email = inMessage.getPrincipalEmail();
        String message = inMessage.getData().getMessage();

        if (!pushNotificationDelegate.checkIfUserIsLocal(id)) {
         log.info("user {} not connected to this server, another instance will handle the message, exiting...", id);
         return;
        }
[...]
```